# PowerShell get Variable from other running ps1 file

Tags: powershell, variables

I'm calling another.ps1 script from my current.ps1 script.
for example -

& "c:\temp\another.ps1"

in this another.ps1 script I'm creating a variable -

$ComputeramName = "My new comp name"

I'd like to use $ComputeramName in my current.ps1 running script.

can it be done without writing the $VAR output into txt file or using it as a function.

thank you

Comment: if you dot-source the script like `. "c:\temp\another.ps1"` instead of call `&`, then it will update the variables in the context of `current.ps1`.

Comment: A cleaner solution than dot-sourcing is to _output_ the variable from the called script. In "another.ps1" just write `$ComputeramName` on its own line, which implicitly outputs it. Then in "current.ps1" you can do `$ComputeramName = & "c:\temp\another.ps1"` to capture the output from the other script. This way only the necessary variable gets transfered between scripts, instead of making _all_ other, internal variables of "another.ps1" available too.

Comment: thank you!! I didn't knew about & and . for calling a script.